# Qual o significado de "você ainda cai daí"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Eu vi num texto:

> -Cuidado! Você ainda cai daí.
>
> -Não caio nada!

Procurei na internet mas não percebi o que está dizendo! Alguém pode explicar o que significa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> -Be careful! You'll end up falling from there!
>
> -No I won't!

- Você cai: verbo [cair](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cair) (to fall), no presente (terceira pessoa do presente do indicativo: ver a [tabela de conjugação do verbo](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/cair));
- Daí: de+aí (from there);
- Você cai daí: "you fall from there", or "you are falling from there";
- Você *ainda* cai daí: "you will end up falling from there".

---

A palavra "ainda" tem normalmente um significado de "yet":

> *Ainda* não liguei à minha mãe = I have not called my mother *yet*.

Mas neste caso tem um significado mais ou menos de... risco de algo ir acontecer, ou iminência de algo ir acontecer: *<something> is bound to happen*.

Comment: Gostava de ver mais respostas a esta pergunta. Não se acanhem! Respondam num formato diferente, ou uma resposta mais simples, ou uma mais completa, ou... :)

Answer (score 4):

Not much to add to what has already been said by @ANeves. I would only mention the following:

"Você ainda cai daí" is **a colloquialism** and, in this case, the present tense is being used for a future action: "você ainda vai cair daí" (ainda cairá). It's similar to:

- Você ainda me paga. (just you wait, there will be retaliation)
- Você ainda vai ver o que é bom pra tosse. (you just wait for the consequences)
- Você ainda vai se arrepender. (you'll regret later, just wait)

All these sentences use "vai" (presente do indicativo) for something that will happen in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Colocando outras alternativas de tradução, além das já dadas na [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/7733/2764) do ANeves, que aliás é mais completa.

> - Watch out! You might fall from there. / You'll eventually fall from there.
> - No way! / Of course I won't!